# Loop through array of emails in Mandrill

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mandrill

I've got a form that needs to send to different emails depending on the user's selection. I am populating a string variable with the addresses and exploding them into an array.

```
$emailAddresses = $_POST['addressList'];
$sendTo = explode(',', $emailAddresses);
```

Let's say for now that returns an array of

```
$sendTo[0] = "email1@testing.com";
$sendTo[1] = "email2@testing.com";
```

I can send to each email address by manually grabbing the positions

```
'to' => array(
        array('email' => $sendTo[0]),
        array('email' => $sendTo[1])
    )
```

This will send properly. But since the length of the array is dynamic, I need to be able to loop through it. PHP is not my first language so I'm not sure where I'd position the loop in this array.

Where do I write the loop and how to I make sure its syntax stays correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a foreach loop:

```
$to = array()
foreach($sendTo as $email)
{
   $to[] = array('email' => $email);
}


...

'to' => $to
```

Comment: Bingo, now I know a little more about PHP. Thank you!